# Найти присвоение случайных чисел сумма не превышающая 9

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Надо найти сумму генерируюшихся элементов. То есть генерируется на пример 15 чисел в интервале [-8,8], оно может повторятся но суть в том что сумма в конечном не превышало 9, то есть надо наверное проверку поставить, если сумма превышает 9, то отминусуем минус числами. И будет исключение сумма не должен быть равен 5. У меня генерируется элементы и рассчитывается сумма, но как сделать так что бы сумма не превышало 9?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();            
Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
int bir = 0, sum = 0;

timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
  if (bir == 1) timer.Stop();
  int n = r.Next(-8, 8);
  label1.Text = n.ToString();
  sum += n;
  bir--;
};
button1.Click += (s, e) =>        
{
  timer.Start();
  timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
  bir = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);                
};
```

Comment: Задача сформулирована сумбурно, что имеется в виду - с помощью генератора равномерно распределенных случайных чисел в интервале 
 [-8,8], получит выборку заданного длины сумма которой < 9 и нет 5 ?

Comment: Что в этом сумбурного?

   ' using System;
 
    namespace MyProg
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 9 - i; j++)
                {
                    if (i + j == 5) continue;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", i, j, i + j);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    }'

Comment: генерируется на пример 15 чисел в интервале [-8,8], оно может повторятся но суть в том что сумма в конечном не превышает 9, то есть надо наверное проверку поставить, если сумма превышает 9, то отминусуем минус числами. И будет исключение сумма не должен быть равен 5.

Comment: Видимо,  "...label1..." не "... генерируется числа от -8 до 8...", а на label1 выводится результат, и запуск процедуры генерации осуществляется не по таймеру, а по событию на textBlock "навроде" onEditReady() (не помню точно название). То есть Ваша формулировка проблемы свидетельствует о полном непонимании, того что Вы хотите

Comment: Ваша уточнение проливает свет, я оформлю, что нужно делать в виде ответа

Comment: Да было бы здорово! Наверное я просто не правилно задал вопрос в теме

Comment: Но я это сделаю, когда появиться окно на работе, так что Вам придется подождать, а лучший вариант, это еще раз четко сформулировать проблему (без сумбура) и попробовать решить самому. Правильная формулировка задачи - 90% ее решения.

Comment: Желательно научиться хорошо формулировать вопрос, изолировать вопрос от всего того что именно к вопросу не относится. Что бы читающему сразу была понятна суть вопроса, и это работа того кто задаёт вопрос. Относится ли label и textbox к сути вопроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        int sumLength = 27;  //заданное число элементов в сумме. Вы его получаете путем преобразования строки из Вашего textBox 

        List<int> sumItems = new List<int>();  //На всякий случай сохраним последовательсть, которая дает сумму с нужными Вам свойствами.

        Random rand = new Random();


        int sum = 0; //Ваша искомая сумма

        int currentSumItemNumber=0;

        //Отбираем из случайной последлвательности числа, которые дадут сумму с требуемым свойством из заданного числа слагаемых
        while(currentSumItemNumber < sumLength)
        {
            int currRand = rand.Next(-8, 8);

            int nextSumValue = sum + currRand;
            if (nextSumValue == 5) continue;
            if (nextSumValue > 9) continue;

            sum = nextSumValue;
            sumItems.Add(currRand);
            currentSumItemNumber++;
        }

       // После выполнения цикла sum содержит искомую сумму, которую Вы выводите на Ваш label1, а sumItems сохранена случайная подпоследовательность
```

Comment: А как сделать так что бы рандом числа мигали, так как у меня диапазон коротки числа редко повторяются, и я не замечаю разницы когда генерируется следующий элемент?  Пишу так  timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                label9.Visible = !label9.Visible;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);     но не совподает с интервалом генерации.

Comment: @koni-men, извините но я смогу Вами заняться только поздно вечером и то не уверен. Мой совет, сформулируйте свою новую проблему ("как сделать, чтобы моргало") отдельным новым вопросом. Это привлечет внимание большего числа людей, которые возможно найдут время, чтобы подсказать Вам решение.

Comment: ок, хорошо, огромное спасибо за помощь и совет!

Answer (score 0):

Вроде сработало, спасибо большое! Все же можете проверить, может я не правильно переписал ваш код? И я добавил (-9 < nextSum), потому что в результате выходит много минусовых сумм.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();             
Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
List<int> sumItems = new List<int>();
int sum = 0, bir = 27;
timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
  {
     if (bir == 1) timer.Stop();
     {  int currentSumItemNumber = 0;

        while (currentSumItemNumber < bir)
              {
                  int n = r.Next(-5, 8);
                  label1.Text = n.ToString();
                  int nextSum = sum + n;
                  if (nextSum == 5) continue;
                  if ((-9 < nextSum ) & (nextSum > 9)) continue;
                  sum = nextSum;
                  sumItems.Add(n);
                  currentSumItemNumber++;
              }  
          bir--;
      }
  };

button1.Click += (s, e) =>        
   {
      timer.Start();
      timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
      bir = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);                
   };
```